# Could Harry Potter have used the Room of Requirement to get Felix Felicis?

Tags: harry-potter

You can get potions from the Room of Requirement. Dobby got some potions against alcoholism for Winky, as seen in *The Goblet of Fire*.

So could Harry Potter have gotten some Felix Felicis in the 6th volume before he left Hogwarts?

Comment: @mithrandir better?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possibly because Felix Felicis is a potion that should be drunk, and the room cannot provide any kind of food, as food is one of the five exceptions in Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration

From Wiki, we have,

> In 1995, Harry Potter asked Dobby if he knew of a place where
>   Dumbledore's Army could safely meet. Dobby told Harry of what the
>   house-elves called the "Come and Go Room" or "Room of Requirement",
>   which he had used to treat Winky after she had gotten drunk on
>   Butterbeer, as the room **filled with antidotes to butterbeer** and an
>   elf-sized bed for Winky to sleep off her inebriation. He also said
>   that Argus Filch had found extra cleaning supplies in the room. During
>   the first D.A. meeting, Fred and George Weasley revealed that it had
>   once taken the form of a broom cupboard which they had used to hide
>   from Filch.

I don't have the exact book quote at hand but if I remember correctly the books call them antidotes as well instead of potions. Perhaps those were the types of antidotes that need not be ingested (IV injections maybe?)

Comment: Something that is drunk is *not* food. Counterexample: wizards can create water using *aguamenti*. However some ingredients of the potion may be considered food (e.g. pieces of animals and stuff like that)

Comment: I'm pretty sure aquamenti is a summoning charm and doesn't really create water. Maybe more expert users can provide some references

Comment: I think i read somewhere that things *created* by the RoR could not be taken out (as opposed to those previously brought in).  In that case, the antidotes might have worked only in the room (hence the bed).  Food that stops working on leaving would be much more dangerous than a potion which has already done its job, I think.  Or they might work because someone had previously brought in those ingredients, who knows.

Comment: @user13267 If it weren't a summoning charm and it DID create water, there would be no problems on Earth. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact canon fact we can determine (as far as I can remember), but it could be possible as user12367 said that The room may create potions. But the things you mentioned (Antidotes) can be whipped in a jiffy. They are not too complicated nor take too much time to make.

But Felix Felicis is a very complicated potion to brew, normally taking six months or more. The time period involved is very long, So even if the Room is able to make it, it would still take six months for the thing to appear, and the person asking for it should not leave the room for the time. I don't think Harry could have spent this much time....